# RLM - how to lock a floating license to a group of users

Tags: licensing

I have a few floating licenses managed by RLM server. Is there any possibility to lock only one license to a group of people?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question here: http://docs.fabric-engine.com/FabricEngine/1.15.2/HTML/LicensingGuide/floating.html

You have to update file.opt, or create a new one in case it doesn't exist.
It should contains:

```
GROUP it user1 user2 user3  
RESERVE 1 softwarename GROUP it
```

where 'it' is the group name and 'user1', 'user2', 'user3' are the usernames; and 'softwarename' is the name used by the vendor when you get the license. For example the floating license looks like this:

```
LICENSE foundry hieroplayer_i 2015.1025 permanent 4 share=h ........
```

the 'softwerename' will be 'hieroplayer_i'